# How to apply a formula to all columns in a Dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'MA1': [ float("nan"),  float("nan"),      -1,   1],
        'MA2': [ float("nan"),            -1,       0,   0],
        'MA3': [            0,             0,       1,  -1]}
df_input = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['MA1', 'MA2', 'MA3'])
```

[image]

My goal is for every column, if the first non nan and non zero value is -1, to set it to 0.

**Clarification:**

The goal is only to set to 0 if the first non 0 and non nan value is -1. If it is 1 or anything else, then leave it there.

[image]

What is the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over the columns and use `DataFrame.loc` to assign the 0 when the first valid value is `-1`:

```
dft = df_input.replace(0, np.NaN)

for col in df_input.columns:
    idxmin = dft[col].idxmin()
    if df_input.loc[idxmin, col] == -1:
        df_input.loc[idxmin, col] = 0

   MA1  MA2  MA3
0  NaN  NaN    0
1  NaN  0.0    0
2  0.0  0.0    1
3  1.0  0.0    0
```

---

Or more efficient by using `DataFrame.idxmin` instead so we dont have to to call `Series.idxmin` for each iteration in our loop:

```
dft = df_input.replace(0, np.NaN).idxmin()

for col, idx in dft.iteritems():
    if df_input.loc[idx, col] == -1:
        df_input.loc[idx, col] = 0

   MA1  MA2  MA3
0  NaN  NaN    0
1  NaN  0.0    0
2  0.0  0.0    1
3  1.0  0.0    0
```

Comment: This way is almost perfect, except it sets to 0 every first -1, while I only want that in the case where the -1 is the first non zero and non nan value.

Comment: Can you then adjust your example input and expected output? Because based on your input data and your expected output (screenshot on the bottom), this solution gives the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

Being at the end of one year using python, I'm trying to be better at implementing higher performing solutions, so I thought I would test the performance of my answer versus other's (realizing that my answer would be the slowest -- *from the dataframe I created*, it ended up being `50,000x` slower than the best answer! Woah!). Also, here is a good article about pandas and performance: https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

My traditional slow looping method looped through 3 columns almost 100,000 times (length of dataframe), while the best answer looped through 3 columns one time as it `idx.min()` identified the relevant row, making it unnecessary to loop through them all.

Here is a dataframe with 100,000 rows and 4 columns that I used to test vs. @Erfan and @DerekO:

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100000,4)).astype(float), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_input.iloc[99998:, 0:4] = -1
```

My Answer (slowest) `2.78 s ± 269 ms per loop`:

```
for col in df_input.columns:
    for row in range(len(df_input.index)):
        if df_input.loc[row, col] == -1:
            df_input.loc[row, col] = 0
            break    
df_input
```

Derek O's answer #1: `283 ms ± 13.2 ms per loop` 10x faster than my answer!

Erfan's answer #1: `2.73 ms ± 135 µs per loop` 1,000x faster than my answer!

Erfan's answer #2: `54.8 µs ± 5.65 µs per loop` 50,000x faster than my answer!

Comment: Nice experiment, good to see how much of an efficiency impact the vectorized solutions make!

Answer (score 0):

Apply a custom function to each column. The custom function loops through the column's values to find the first non-nan, non-zero value, then returns the new column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def set_column(col_values):
    for index, value in enumerate(col_values):
        if value != 0 and not np.isnan(value):
            if value == -1:
                col_values[index] = 0
                return col_values
            else:
                return col_values

data = {'MA1': [ float("nan"),  float("nan"),      -1,   1],
        'MA2': [ float("nan"),            -1,       0,   0],
        'MA3': [            0,             0,       1,   0]}

df_input = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['MA1', 'MA2', 'MA3'])
df_output = df_input.copy().apply(lambda x: set_column(x), axis = 0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df_output
   MA1  MA2  MA3
0  NaN  NaN    0
1  NaN  0.0    0
2  0.0  0.0    1
3  1.0  0.0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a modification of @Erfan's answer.

As I explain in my **Update** edit, I want to only set it to zero if the first non zero and non nan value is -1. If it anything else, then don't do anything for that column.

```
df_min = df_input(0, np.NaN).idxmin()
df_max = df_input(0, np.NaN).idxmax()
for col, idx in df_min.iteritems():
    if df_input[idx, col] == -1 and idx < df_max[col]:
        df_input[idx, col] = 0
```